# How to json_decode using foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to parse the form submitted hidden input text using a foreach loop.

```
<input type="hidden" id="snippet_tags" name="snippet_tags[]" value="["88","92","96","98"]">
```

Get this using the following function

```
$snippet_tags = json_decode($_POST['snippet_tags'], true);
```

and parse the values using foreach loop

```
foreach ($snippet_tags as $selectedOption){

                        $ins_snippet_tag_data = array(
                            'snippet_id' => $insertDataReturnLastId,
                            'tag_id' => $selectedOption,
                            'priority' => 1,

                        );

                 $this->Constant_model->insertDataReturnLastId('snippets_tags', $ins_snippet_tag_data);

                }
```

Here the problem is values of tag_id is not saving in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same quotes to delimit the value and the strings inside it. You need to use single quotes around the value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="snippet_tags" name="snippet_tags[]" value='["88","92","96","98"]'>
```

The way you wrote it, it's treated as if you'd written `value="["` and the rest is ignored.

Also, since you have `[]` after the name, `$_POST['snippet_tags']` will be an array, so you need to loop over it.

```
foreach ($_POST['snippet_tags'] as $json) {
    $snippet_tags = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach ($snippet_tags as $selectedOption){
        $ins_snippet_tag_data = array(
            'snippet_id' => $insertDataReturnLastId,
            'tag_id' => $selectedOption,
            'priority' => 1,
        );
        $this->Constant_model->insertDataReturnLastId('snippets_tags', $ins_snippet_tag_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am saving these like this - $('#snippet_tags').val(JSON.stringify(snippettags));

Comment: Are there more than one of these inputs? Usually you use array-style names when you have multiple inputs of the same kind.